# Materials intersection problem (Archimesh addon)

Tags: materials

I'm trying to make an interior, and I've got a problem. I use the Archimesh addon. I've created a room with four walls that already have a Wall_material attached to them. I want to change the material of parts of walls next to the shower. I add a loop cut, then add new material to these parts, but the old material does not go anywhere. The result is the intersection of materials. How to solve this problem? Here are the screenshots.

Пытаюсь сделать интерьер, и у меня возникла проблема. Пользуюсь аддоном Archimesh. Создаю комнату с четырьмя стенами, которые уже имеют прикрученный материал Wall_material. Я хочу у двух стен рядом с душевой кабиной, добавив loop cut, поменять материал. Собственно материал я новый добавляю, однако старый никуда не девается. В итоге получается пересечение материалов. Как решить данную проблему? Вот скриншоты.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like you there is a bit of z-fighting. Is it possible you have duplicate those faces?

Comment: @Carlo You are right. Checked right now. I had 2 rooms. I don't know why it happened. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Carlo for the advice. I just had 2 rooms at the same place that caused z-fighting.[image]
[image]

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't forget to accept your own answer if it fully adderesses your needs.

Comment: @Carlo Sure. I will do it in 2 days.